# how to avoid multiple definitions when making copies of header files

Tags: c

I came across this problem and was trying to figure out the best solution.

I am currently working on a library called `lib1.h` and making some changes to it. I don't want to modify the original file directly so I made a copy and named it `lib2.h`.

All declaration and definitions are coded in `lib1.h` and `lib2.h`, `lib1.c` and `lib2.c`, respectively. The code looks like this:

```c
/* lib1.h */
#ifndef LIB1_H
#define LIB1_H

int method1();
int method2();
...

#endif
```

```c
/* lib2.h */
#ifndef LIB2_H
#define LIB2_H

int method1();
int method2();
...

#endif
```

```c
/* lib1.c */
#include "lib1.h"

int method1()
{
 // old implementation 
};
int method2()
{
 // old implementation 
};
...
```

```c
/* lib2.c */
#include "lib2.h"

int method1()
{
 // new implementation 
};
int method2()
{
 // new implementation 
};
...
```

Since I am not changing the names of all functions, I am getting `multiple definition` errors. My current solution is to move the original library out of the current directory and do a `make clean` and then compile. While this solution works for me, I am just curious if there is any way to keep the two header files in the same directory, or what is a better workflow.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: you have two options: 1- add some suffix to your new methods like `ex`(extended). 2- use c++ namespaces!.

Comment: Prior to moving lib1 out of the folder, what command were you using to actually compile/link your code?

Comment: @jarmod it is a custom nuttx system running on an embedded system, and I am using `make` to complie.

Comment: Make a backup in a separate directory. Modify files as needed. Refer back to originals as needed. Having two files with the same contents in the same directory is making your life difficult for no benefit that I can see.

Comment: @MMD if I were to go with option 1, would the changes be something like this in `lib2.h`? `ex int method1()`? Would namespaces also work in c?

Comment: @TimRandall thank you for pointing this out, now I couldn't really see any benefits behind having same contents in the same directory

Comment: the new name would be `int method1_ex()` or `int method1Ex()` or similar. and about namespaces... no there is no way to create a namespace in **c**

Comment: @YihanHu Make itself doesn't compile/link. It runs whatever your Makefile tells it to, typically a compiler and linker. The `multiple definition` error is from the linker. Why are you linking both lib1 and lib2 together? Ideally you wouldn't have the same defined methods in code in the same folder, per earlier comments, but there's no technical reason it won't work, assuming that you only compile and link the correct set of things.

Comment: @MMD thank you. that's definitely one way around this. I think I'd just do what Tim Randall said and keep the original in a different folder. I think that works better for me.

Comment: @jarmod Ah I see. Alright I will just link the files that are needed. Thank you for the pointer!

Comment: my 2 cents, set up a git repo locally. This is very little effort and will track all changes made to your files. No need for separate folder backups, renaming files, renaming functions, etc. If you make some changes you want to back out, it's easy to revert. For changes you want to keep, easy to store them on another branch. Git does come with a bit of a learning curve, but that won't be wasted time as it's used widely in industry.

Comment: On another note: `int method();` **is not a prototype**. It is an old-style K&R function declaration. You should always use `int method(void);`, which is a proper prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple definitions is a linker error, not compilation error. Why do you link both libraries? I guess you need only the newer (fixed) one.
There are a few solutions:

1. Delete the old code,
2. Put #ifdef 0 on the old code, or move it to separate directory
3. Use -DNEW_CODE flag in make file and use #ifndef NEW_CODE in old library and #ifdef NEW_CODE in new library. You can quickly switch between versions by editing compilation flags
4. Just dont include the older version in your make file. Even if you compile it, dont link it.
5. If you need both versions of library (to compare results?) use prefix to functions or compile as C++ and wrap the functions in name spaces
6. Use macro hacks to automatically add prefix or suffix to function names. Really dont recommend this approach.
7. Use source control, like git, and change the library in place, and maintain only 1 copy. you can always revert your commits to get the previos version